# Tensor products of finite abelian groups and square maps

Tags: group-theory, modules, tensor-products, abelian-groups

For $G,H$ (possibly finite) abelian groups, we denote the square map on $G$ by $\operatorname{sq}_G$:
$$\operatorname{sq}_G:G \to 2G, \quad g \mapsto 2g.$$
Moreover, we denote the canonical projection from $G \oplus H$ to $G \otimes_\mathbb{Z} H$ by $\pi_{G,H}$:
$$\pi_{G,H}:G \oplus H \to G \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} H, \quad (x,y) \mapsto x \otimes y.$$

I feel a bit embarrassed, but somehow I confused myself a bit when it comes to the compatiblity of $\operatorname{sq}$ and $\pi$. I would like to know if the following diagram commutes:[image]
In particular, does there exist a unique isomorphism $\varphi$ making the diagram commute? I would say yes because of the universal property of $2G \otimes 2G$.

On the other hand, we then would have $\varphi(2x \otimes 2y)=2\,x \otimes y$. So "considering $2G \otimes 2G$ as a subgroup of $G \otimes G$" and setting $G= \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}, \,x=\bar{1}=y$, we would have $\varphi(0)=\bar{2} \otimes \bar{1}$. I think that the mistake here is to consider $2G \otimes 2G$ as a subgroup of $G \otimes G$. In particular, $\bar{2} \otimes \bar{2}$ does not vanish in $2G \otimes 2G$, right?

EDIT: As Randall noted, $\pi$ is not a homomorphism so the arrow in the middle doesn't make sense.. however, the map $\varphi$ should exist anyway by the universal property of the coimage $2(G\otimes G)\cong (G\otimes G)/(G\otimes G)_2$, making at least the bottom of the diagram commute. It is an isomorphism: epic since both maps at the bottom are epic (tensor product preserves epi's) and monic since the orders of both groups coincide (in the finite case).

Comment: You do understand that $\pi_{G,H}$ is not a homomorphism, right?

Comment: Wait, did I use this somewhere..? Oh, the restriction doesn't make sense! Thx!